# The first row after scroll, does not allow drop on a gridview

Tags: android, android-gridview

I'm trying to scroll a `gridview` when I drag one view, and it works, but in the views from the first row that appears after the scroll, I can't do drop, but in the rest views yes.
Someone knows why.

Thank you very much in advance. please help me I'm desperate.

Drag listener:

```
public boolean onDrag(View v, DragEvent event) {            
    int action = event.getAction();

    //VistaOrigen>>
    View vOrig = (View) event.getLocalState ();
    //VistaDestino>> 
    View vDest = v;

    switch (action) {
        case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED:
          //Realizamos el cambio de posiciones de los pictogramas:
          posOrig = losPictos.indexOf(vOrig.getTag());

          break;
        case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_LOCATION: 
            if (shouldScrollUp(v, event))
                vComunicador.getPanelPictogramas().smoothScrollByOffset(-3);                    
            else if (shouldScrollDown(v, event))
                vComunicador.getPanelPictogramas().smoothScrollByOffset(3);

            break;
        case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED:
                v.setAlpha(0.5f);
          break;
        case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_EXITED:
                v.setAlpha(1f);
          break;
        case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP:             
            //Drop 
            break;
        case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENDED:
            //Ocultamos el m¡panel de Menú Elimiar y Editar:
            vComunicador.mMostrarPanelEditar(false, false, false);
        default:
            break;
    }
    return true;
}
```

After `smoothScrollByOffset(-3)`, in the first line of the `gridview`, drag listener not working.

Comment: Add the code where it happens, to see how have you done and probably people will help you easyly

Comment: The thing is that for some reason during the recycling of views that makes android, the first row of my gridview after scrolling via smoothScrollByOffset (-3 ) , are losing onDragListener ... can it be? , thank you very much for answering.

Comment: Someone would think what is happening?
Thanks!.